# Columns with same name appearing as different columns Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, multiple-columns

```
select 
    timestamp, organization_id, cluster_safe_name,node_name, correlation_id, cascade_peer_reachability,
    is_cascade, is_cascade_client, device_id, device_type,
    case when audio_main_rx_bitrate > 0 or audio_main_tx_bitrate > 0 then 'true' end as audio_main,
    case when audio_main_rx_bitrate > 0 or audio_main_tx_bitrate > 0 then 'false' end as audio_slides,
    case when audio_main_rx_bitrate > 0 or audio_main_tx_bitrate > 0 then 'false' end as video_main,
    case when audio_main_rx_bitrate > 0 or audio_main_tx_bitrate > 0 then 'false' end as video_slides,
    case when audio_main_rx_bitrate > 0 or audio_main_tx_bitrate > 0 then audio_main_rx_bitrate end as rx_rtcp_byte,
    case when audio_main_rx_bitrate > 0 or audio_main_tx_bitrate > 0 then audio_main_tx_bitrate end as tx_rtcp_byte,
    case when audio_slides_rx_bitrate > 0 or audio_slides_tx_bitrate > 0 then 'false' end as audio_main,
    case when audio_slides_rx_bitrate > 0 or audio_slides_tx_bitrate > 0 then 'true' end as audio_slides,
    case when audio_slides_rx_bitrate > 0 or audio_slides_tx_bitrate > 0 then 'false' end as video_main,
    case when audio_slides_rx_bitrate > 0 or audio_slides_tx_bitrate > 0 then 'false' end as video_slides,
    case when audio_slides_rx_bitrate > 0 or audio_slides_tx_bitrate > 0 then audio_slides_rx_bitrate end as rx_rtcp_byte,
    case when audio_slides_rx_bitrate > 0 or audio_slides_tx_bitrate > 0 then audio_slides_tx_bitrate end as tx_rtcp_byte
from (
select 
    timestamp, organization_id, cluster_safe_name, node_name, correlation_id, cascade_peer_reachability,
    is_cascade, is_cascade_client, device_id, device_type,
    audio_main_rx_bitrate, audio_main_tx_bitrate,
    audio_slides_rx_bitrate, audio_slides_tx_bitrate
from homer_cascade_bandwidth_usage_metrics_v2 hcbumv 
) t
where correlation_id = '62183eb2-94c7-49ff-a98a-3a171d75ac07'   
order by timestamp desc;
```

I have written this query, notice that audio_main column is appearing 2 times in case statement. As a result of this query I have 2 seperate audio_main columns while I want one column. Can this be done with the same query or should I write 2 diff queries

Comment: You used the same alias twice, so what do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You should re-write the CASE statement in order to include the two possible combination of events in each of the same columns. I'd go with the following:

```sql
case 
  when audio_main_rx_bitrate > 0 or audio_main_tx_bitrate > 0 then true
  when audio_slides_rx_bitrate > 0 or audio_slides_tx_bitrate > 0 then false 
end as audio_main,
case 
  when audio_slides_rx_bitrate > 0 or audio_slides_tx_bitrate > 0 then true
  when audio_main_rx_bitrate > 0 or audio_main_tx_bitrate > 0 then false
end as audio_slides,
[...]
```

Also, note that if you quote both `'true'` and `'false'`, you will be creating a string instead of a boolean field.